# Cosa vuol dire "stare su" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il contesto*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> Aver davanti l'uomo, parlargli, conoscerlo, per Rogas contava più degli indizi, più dei fatti stessi. "Un fatto è un sacco vuoto". Bisogna metterci dentro l'uomo, la persona, il personaggio perché **stia su**.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "stare su" in questo passaggio? Alla [voce "stare su" del dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/stare-su) ho trovato

> **1** colloq., farsi coraggio, non abbattersi, spec. in esortazioni: *coraggio, sta' su* 
>   **2** colloq., rimanere sveglio fino a tarda ora perché impegnato in un lavoro, in un divertimento, ecc.: *sono stato su fino alle tre*

ma queste accezioni non sembrano avere senso nel contesto del testo.

Comment: In questo caso significa letteralmente "stare ritto, in piedi".Un sacco vuoto è floscio, si accascia a terra e non è utile; il personaggio che parla dice che i fatti sono metaforicamente come un sacco, che va riempito con le persone (o, meglio, la conoscenza di queste) perché stia in piedi ovvero abbia una consistenza e, di conseguenza un significato.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **stare** v. intr. [..] **3.** [...] *s. su*, tenersi ritto, reggersi sulla vita (anche di cosa, reggersi in posizione verticale) [...]
>   (dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stare/))

In questo caso significa essenzialmente *non cadere*. Per esempio

> Ho provato a piantare l'ombrellone venti volte, ma non vuole proprio stare su.

Nel contesto, Rogas sta spiegando perché è necessario non solo conoscere i fatti del caso, ma anche incontrare le persone coinvolte, altrimenti la nostra conoscenza è come un sacco vuoto, che manca della sostanza interiore che fa stare in piedi un sacco pieno.